# How do i know that where the arr variable came from?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, youtube

Here is the full Source of Script : https://gist.github.com/x10hassan/454347585de3c2312f1c#file-cipher

About the Script and Little Background:

this script is used to  get and decode the Youtube download link and it's just structure code at the moment which works good and servers it's purpose and i'm trying to convert it to function.

My Problem :

Have a Look at Complete Source Code there is Foreach Statement on **line 94**

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
                    parse_str($link,$linkarr);

                    // parse link array one by one and decrypt the signature
                    $dlinks[$linkarr['itag']] = $linkarr['url'] . "&signature=" . decrypt($linkarr['s'],$algo);
                    echo $linkarr['itag'].'<br />';
                    echo $dlinks[$linkarr['itag']].'<br /><br />';
                }
```

There is a $linkarr variable where does it comes from and what purpose does it serves , the compiled results can be found here : http://yt.hassannaseer.com/sb/cipher.php

i'm trying to create a function which accepts a video id and return a associative array with the key containing “itag” and value to “decoded youtube download link”? can someone help me with that?

Comment: You look at the docs for [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to see where `$linkarr` comes from

Comment: @MarkBaker I got that one, can you guide me on function problem as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the full code here: [Github/bitnol](https://github.com/bitnol/CipherAPI/blob/master/modules.php)

For reference check this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Author: Akhilesh Chandra Gupta
 * Author URI: http://www.bitnol.com
 * API URI: http://api.gitnol.com
 * Description: Modular demo of the application of Cipher API
 * License: MIT License
 */

// Video with cipher signature 
$video_id = "zDrNLZ1uJ2w";
$results = getYTLink($video_id);
var_dump($results);

function getYTLink($video_id){

    // get_video_info url formation
    // although for cipher signature we have to get the details from the video's webapge not from get_video_info object
    $info_url = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?el=detailpage&asv=3&video_id=".$video_id;

    // youtube webpage url formation
    $yt_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$video_id.'&gl=US&persist_gl=1&hl=en&persist_hl=1';;

    // get the contents from the url
    $raw_data = file_get_contents($info_url);

    // parse the data received and save it as an array
    $output = array();
    parse_str($raw_data,$output);

    // check the status of the get_video_info object
    if($output['status']=='ok'){

        // check for the cipher signature
        $cipher = (isset($output['use_cipher_signature']) &&  $output['use_cipher_signature']=='True') ? true : false;

        // If cipher is true then we have to decode it
        if($cipher == true){

            // if cipher is true then we have to change the plan and get the details from the video's youtube wbe page
            $yt_html = file_get_contents($yt_url);

            // parse for the script containing the configuration
            preg_match('/ytplayer.config = {(.*?)};/',$yt_html,$match);
            $yt_object = @json_decode('{'.$match[1].'}') ;

            /// check if we are able to parse data
            if(!is_object($yt_object)){
                //'Sorry! Unable to parse Data';
                return 'Error Code 1';
            }else{

                // parse available formats
                $formats = $yt_object->args->url_encoded_fmt_stream_map;
                // get the player id from assets section
                $player_id = strbtwn($yt_object->assets->js,'html5player-','.js');
                $player_id = explode("/", $player_id);
                $player_id = $player_id[0];

                // get the algo dictionary
                // first check if the file exists
                if(file_exists('./algo.json'))
                    $algos = json_decode(file_get_contents('algo.json'),true);
                else{
                    // API call to fetch the algo dictionary
                    $algos_dict = file_get_contents("http://api.gitnol.com/getAlgo.php?playerID=".$player_id);

                    // saving the algo dictonary in local env for easy access
                    // Note: Developers should save the dictionary in their local env. 
                    // Only make the API call for the new player ids which is not present in the algo dictionary.
                    // Repeated violation will results in IP ban.
                    file_put_contents('algo.json', $algos_dict);

                    $algos = json_decode($algos_dict,true);
                }

                /// check if the algo exist for the given player id
                if(!array_key_exists($player_id, $algos)){

                    // if the algo dictionary is old then fetch a new one
                    $algos_dict = file_get_contents("http://api.gitnol.com/getAlgo.php?playerID=".$player_id);
                    file_put_contents('algo.json', $algos_dict);

                    $algos = json_decode($algos_dict,true);
                    $algo = $algos[$player_id][1];

                }else{
                    $algo = $algos[$player_id][1];
                }

                // download links formation
                $dlinks = array();
                $links  = explode(',',$formats);


                foreach ($links as $link) {
                    parse_str($link,$linkarr);

                    // parse link array one by one and decrypt the signature
                    $dlinks[$linkarr['itag']] = $linkarr['url'] . "&signature=" . decrypt($linkarr['s'],$algo);
                }
                return $dlinks;
            }

        }else{
            //'Video Is not cipher not needed to decode';
            return 'Error Code 2'; 
        }
    }else{
        //'Unable to get Video Info';
        return 'Error Code 3'; 
    }
}
// string helper function
function strbtwn($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}

// signature decoding 
// parse the python string operation into php string operation
function decrypt($sig,$algo){
    $funcarr = explode(' + ', $algo);
    $decrypt = '';
    foreach($funcarr as $singfunc){
        $singfunc = substr($singfunc,2,-1);
        $operators = explode(':', $singfunc);
        if (sizeof($operators) == 1) {
            $decrypt .= $sig[$operators[0]];
        }
        if (sizeof($operators) == 2) {
            if($operators[0] == ''){
                $decrypt .= substr($sig, 0 ,$operators[1]);
            }
            if($operators[1] == ''){
                $decrypt .= substr($sig, $operators[0]);
            }
            if($operators[0] >= 0 && $operators[1] >= 0){
                $decrypt .= substr($sig, $operators[0], $operators[1] - $operators[0]);
            }
        }
        if (sizeof($operators) == 3) {
            if($operators[0] == '' && $operators[1] == ''){
                $decrypt .= strrev($sig);
            }
            if($operators[0] >=0 && $operators[1] == ''){
                $decrypt .= strrev(substr($sig, 0, $operators[0] + 1));
            }
            if($operators[0] >=0 && $operators[1] >= 0){
                $decrypt .= strrev(substr($sig, $operators[1] + 1, $operators[0] - $operators[1]));
            }
        }
    }
    return $decrypt;
}
?>
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank You Akhlish this makes it pretty much simple :)